# ElectronJS version 22.0.3: Strange text issue in HTML table rendering

Tags: electron

I'm encountering a strange text issue while rendering a web page in ElectronJS (version 22.0.3).
The text appears to smudge/blur/freeze in the HTML table.
This is very hard to replicate.
The text is updated every 100ms to 5s.

[Screenshot of the behavior. I have blacked out the normal text and highlighted the strange text in red. The left-hand side is Electron and the right-hand side is Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjeRm.png)

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

I've tried to replicate it, but I am unable to do so.
I increased the text updating to be faster and more consistent but I was unable to re-create it.